# kube-metrics-adapter installation at namespace level

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I've a use-case for my REST-API. I'm deploying my REST service to kubernetes. So for Autoscaling my pod, I want to build  Horizontal Pod Autoscaler based on custom-metrics like **Request-Per-Second**. So for that purpose we'll have to create a custom-metrics-adapter like this https://github.com/banzaicloud/banzai-charts/tree/master/kube-metrics-adapter.

But the problem that I'm facing, I don't have access to create any **ClusterRole** or creating **APIService**. I just want to know can we deploy this **kube-metrics-adapter** API at namespace level to which I've access, so that it can provide custom-metrics to HPA. Is it necessary to have this adapter at cluster level?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the chart, the RBAC templates are hard-coded to use clusterroles. You can't install this chart if `tiller` doesn't have cluster-level access. You could try modifying the chart to be namespace scoped, but you'll probably need some level of permissions to the metrics API to register your custom metrics.

Ask a cluster admin if you can get the clusterroles put in?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess this adapter api needs to be deployed at cluster-level. Because for creating APIService (custom.metrics.k8s.io) I'll have to use "apiregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1" to which my namespace don't have access. I guess there is no way to deploy this kube-metrics-adapter at only namespace level.